# I wrote quadratic equations program in python but one solution is being calculated wrong when 2nd one is correct

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to solve quadratic equations using Python, my program finds solutions but first one is being calculated wrong, I checked the code several times and can't find what am I doing wrong

```
a = 2  # random.randint(1, 10)
b = 9  # random.randint(-110, 10000)
c = 4  # random.randint(-10000, 10000000)

d = (b ** 2) + (- 4 * a * c)
print(d)

if d < 0:
    print('x does not exist')
elif d == 0:
    print((-1 * b) / 2 * a)
else:
    print('x exists')


def sqrt(n):
    if n < 0:
        return
    else:
        return n ** 0.5


x_1 = (-1 * b - sqrt(b)) / 4
x_2 = (-1 * b + sqrt(b)) / 4

print(f'solution 1 is: {round(x_1)}, solution 2 is: {round(x_2)}')
```

Comment: Recheck your math. `x_1` and `x_2` only depend on `b` in your code - that can't be correct, can it?

Comment: Isn't that (-b±√D)/2a?? I didn't understand x1 and x2 expressions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the formula:

```
x_1 = (-1 * b - sqrt(b)) / 4
```

`sqrt(b)` should be `sqrt(d)`.

Also in the print statement:

```
print(f'solution 1 is: {round(x_1)}, solution 2 is: {round(x_2)}')
```

The `round` function is confusing.

You could change it to:

```
print(f'solution 1 is: {(x_1)}, solution 2 is: {(x_2)}')
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the round function, I was confused because I was getting -4, 0 solutions instead of -4, -0.5 and was wondering why I was getting that output and now I know, thanks a lot again!

Answer (score 0):

Your x1 and x2 expressions are not correct. It should be:
`x_1=(-1*b+sqrt(d))/(2*a)`

`x_2=(-1*b-sqrt(d))/(2*a)`